# Setup a Jenkins CI server on a QEMU emulation of "Raspberry Pi" (Windows)

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, qemu, raspbian

1. How to set up  a Raspberry 'VM' with **QEMU**
2. Setup Jenkins to run with new **Oracle Java 7**

Comment: This sounds like a totally bizarre thing to do.  Care to explain why you want to do this?

Comment: 'Bizarre' is probably the right word. Well I'm waiting for my Raspberry Pi to be delivered and I wanted to try the setup without leaving garbage on a brand clean installation. Also I can now try out the 'Oracle Java 7' and 'Oracle Java 8 preview' on before hand. Moreover I've been having issue with Jenkins on other devices with small RAM.

Answer (score 6):

## 0. Emulation

1. Download and extract http://sourceforge.net/projects/rpiqemuwindows/
2. Start the QEMU by running run.bat
3. Install and configure Raspbian (user: pi, password: raspberry)
4. Close the QEMU

The vm-image has a very small drive of ~300MB free space which is not enough to install Java + Jenkins. So we need to expand it.

## 1. Expand the volume

1. Expand the **raspbian** image by 10GB, `qemu-img resize 2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian.img +10G`
2. However this is not sufficient, since we also need to extend the partition in the filesystem of the image. So we need to boot GParted live cd, because we can't do it at runtime.
3. Download **GParted Live CD** http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php
4. Copy the files from the `Bios` directory into the QEMU directory, where qemu-system-x86_64.exe is located.
5. Start a normal x86 machine using the command:

   `qemu-system-x86_64.exe -hda 2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian.img -m 512M
   -cdrom gparted-live-0.16.2-1b-i486.iso -boot d -pflash bios.bin`.

   This take a quite bit of time...
6. Resize the partition to fill the disk.
7. Don't forget to actually **apply** before closing.
8. Launch QEMU again and verify that the **rootfs** is now larger using the command `df`

## 2. Install Jenkins

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install jenkins`
3. Stop the service `sudo service jenkins stop`
4. The log `cat /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log` reveals the following:

   ```
   [Winstone] - Beginning extraction from war file
   [Winstone] - Error initializing web application: prefix []
   java.io.IOException: No space left on device
   at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
   at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:282)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.getWebRoot(HostConfiguration.java:273)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:73)
   ...
   at Main.main(Main.java:96)
   ```
5. Jenkins has actually crashed because it tries to extract all files into the **tmpfs** in `/run` which only 10% of your RAM (~20MB with `-m 192`). To fix this we need to edit the `--webroot` parameter to Jenkins to use a another directory.
6. `nano /etc/default/jenkins` 
   edit the following line

   `JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=$JENKINS_RUN/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT ...`

   into

   `JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=$JENKINS_HOME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT ...`

## 3. Install Oracle Java 7 (hard-float)

1. Start the QEMU with `run.bat` again
2. `sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-jdk`
3. List the installed Java versions (Jenkins installs OpenJDK) 
   `update-java-alternatives -l`
4. `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and select the Oracle JDK.
5. Now try `java -version` to ensure that is uses **Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment**

## 4. Start and verify installation

1. `sudo service jenkins start`
2. `tail /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log -f`and wait for **Jenkins is fully up and running**
3. Now try that it is actually up 
   `wget localhost:8080 && nano index.html`

Comment: Download GParted Live CD http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php
Copy the files from the Bios   ...Where is bios directory?

Comment: This is a few years old, they probably changed the file structure. You can try an older version, or try to find the new directory.